# Jquery and Ajax issue

Tags: jquery

I have this jquery function for updating a background image.

var jq = $.noConflict();
    jq(document).ready(function() {

```
jq('#s22').click(function() {
       d = new Date();
      var tableframe3 = jQuery("div .rs4",window.parent.preview.document);
    tableframe3.css("backgroundimage","url(images/bg.png?"+d.getTime());
 });           
 });
```

It does work, but when i add it to my form that uses ajax.updater, then it will only trigger the first time I submit the form. i have to reload the entire page to get it to work again. here is the code i use for submitting my form.

```
<form action="<?=$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'] ?>" method="POST" 
onsubmit="try{                
        showStatus('working...');$(this).request({
        sender:$(this).identify(),

        onSuccess :function(transport){

            try{                
               new Ajax.Updater($($('<?=$function ?>_container').parentNode),'Sites/<?=$function ?>/<?=$item[$this->mainModel->primaryKey] ?>/<?=$index ?>?ajax=true',{evalScripts:true}); showStatus('Complete!',2000);                
            }catch(e){
                showStatus(e.toString(),4000);
            }
        }
    })}catch(e){showStatus(e.toString(),4000)};return false;">
```

this is the submit button :)

```
  <input type="submit"  id="s22" value="Select" />
```

I know the issue is with this Ajax.Updater because when i comment it out then the jquery works on each submit without having to reload the page.

```
 new Ajax.Updater($($('<?=$function ?>_container').parentNode),'Sites/<?=$function ?>/<?=$item[$this->mainModel->primaryKey] ?>/<?=$index ?>?ajax=true',{evalScripts:true}); showStatus('Complete!',2000);
```

I am a newbie with javascript so I have no clue what the issue.

Comment: Try var tableframe3 = jQuery("div .rs4");, I'm not aware of the second argument window.parent.preview.document for jQuery selection?

Comment: i am using iframe so window.parent.preview.document identifies the frame

Comment: i found a work around for this issue. so i am not using ajax to update my div now. thanx for your assistance. should i delete this question?